# Build: unity throws back errors whenever I try to build a game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please guys help me with this. Don't view and pass please
I've been trying to build my game but it keeps throwing back the errors below

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\EventSystem\EventData\PointerEventData.cs(235,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PenStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\EventSystem\UIElements\PanelEventHandler.cs(391,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PenStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 51 seconds (51127 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)ds.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in :0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I created a new project with blank scene for testing but it keeps giving back the exact errors.

Comment: It looks like PenStatus didn't exist before Unity 2022. Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I've solved the issue. I only had to install a lower version of unity editor.